Telegram bot sendMessage problem, Sending duplicate messages
I use bot to send messages to Telegram, but sometimes two duplicate messages appear on Telegram
export async function telegramSendMessage(sendMessage: string) {

    

    const bot = new TelegramBot(TELEGRAM_BOOT_TOKEN, {polling: false});

    const chatId = parseInt(TELEGRAM_CHAT_ID);

    try {
        await bot.sendMessage(chatId, sendMessage, {parse_mode: 'Markdown'});
    } catch (error) {
        logger.error(`Telegram faile: ${error}`);
    }

}

I tried to check the document, but couldn't find this type of problem. Currently, I don't know what caused it

Add a log into the try block where you send the message and check weither you trigger the send twice yourself. I reckon, that it is not an issue of the library, but the error lies in you piece of code.
